# relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: compiling, cmake

I got this error after I run make -j4 after cmake ..

> Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libCnoidUtil.so
>
> /usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libyaml.a(api.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>
> ../../lib/libyaml.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[2]: *** [lib/libCnoidUtil.so.1.6] Error 1
>
> make[1]: *** [src/Util/CMakeFiles/CnoidUtil.dir/all] Error 2
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?
I've tried to read many answer, but I cannot really understand how to solve it.
I've quite new to ubuntu.

Anyone please help!!

Comment: What are you trying to build and where did you get it from? sometimes these kinds of errors occur because the source is not "clean" i.e. contains object files or libraries from a previous build or different system architecture

Comment: @steeldriver 
I could make it once, but when I delete it. I want to remake. But it hasn't worked anymore and show this error

Comment: Does the Makefile provide a `clean` target? if so, did you run it (`make clean`) between builds?

Comment: .I alrealy use "make clean" after error. Then "make" again. But still not working:(